# WYSIWYG editor in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, wysiwyg, openoffice-writer, word-processor

I need help finding a WYSIWYG editor to use in the web application I'm developing.

The boss wants to reach a word-like usability, where you can set header/footer for the pages, see actually what the text look like on a page (not like editing a white textarea), and develop a few functionalities..

I tried using TinyMCE but it has not the page view and it doesn't support header/footer, although I've been able to develop the functionalities he needs.

So basically I searched the web for JavaScript editors that give word look and feel, but didn't find any that suits the boss' needs. Saw and discarded many javascript editors, like CKEditor.
I like a lot JWord, from Pilot Software ([JWord](http://www.pilotltd.com/index_en.jsp?pagenum=90004)), even though it's a bit pricey...

What I'm working with is: JSPs, Tomcat, Java Spring, MySQL.

I'm also trying to embed an instance of Openoffice Writer in my jsp, but with no luck so far.

I'm not worried buying some editors, I'm not paying them myself, so please point me to any software that would fit in :D

Edit: one of my colleagues who works in .NET told me he uses [Text control](http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/) and he finds it very well designed. Is there a way I could use it with my setup? Maybe with a bridge, a double server, etc.

Edit2: @NimChimpsky I already tried googling a bit for this, as I thought of it too, but I found some contrasting posts about it... For example: I need to add a couple of buttons that do queries on db, substitute some placeholders with the results of the previous mentioned queries, etc. Is it even possible to accomplish this with google docs? If so, which programming language have I to use to program those functionalities? Is it possible to insert programmatically header and footer on every page of the document (without the user doing it manually)? Or instead, I read about everywhere that it's tricky to let the user in my web application edit a document, because it's read only, or it shows awful controls/graphic interface... I'm a bit worried about these pieces of info I found on the net.

Comment: whats wrong with TinyMCE? Its the most flexible outthere, and ofcourse you can make it support headers/footers - its all about being creative.

Comment: It has no print layout view (it's all a blank white area with no page margins), it doesn't have native header/footer support (for example an intestation to be replicated on every page, a page counter on the bottom of the page, ecc.). It's not about being creative or not, it's about not reinventing the wheel...

Answer (score 0):

```
The boss wants to reach a word-like usability
```

As Microsoft itself has yet to develop a web interface for its Word product (well it hadn't last time I checked). This is somewhat ambitious.

Embed google docs instead ?

I used tinymce btw for something similar, and you can add the header and footer server side using Java code. And for pdf's [this](http://itextpdf.com/) is well used.

Comment: I couldn't comment here because of the limited space, I edited the question instead. Thank you!

Comment: I already have the java code for inserting the header and footer, but I need them in every page, not at the beginning of the text inserted by the user (maybe of tens of pages) and then the footer at the end of the tenth page.. With tinymce I have not the visual of how the page will look like, and my boss explicitedly told me to not use it, so even though it may be the best option out there I was told not to use it.

Comment: @NimChmpsky I want to know where do store the content of wysisyg editor created by user, I mean in database or in a file. I want to create the same thing, but I have never done such before, can you suggest me smething, where do I store them efficiently